# how to iterate over list of lists in scala

Tags: scala

I want to iterate over a `list[List[String]]` to subset it into a `list[String]` and then store each list from the list of lists in a `val`. The val's name could be anything but it should include each list index in its name.

For example:

```
 val x: List[ List[String]] = List(List("Nike","Apple"), List("James", "Mike"))
```

Desired output:

```
 group_0 : List[String] = List(Nike, Apple)
 group_1 = List[String] = List(James, Mike)
```

Comment: just index your first list? `val group_0 = x(0)` etc

Comment: @Joel, i want  to iterate over the list of lists because i don't know the size of  it in advance. Thanks

Comment: why do you need all the `List[String]`s as separate values? sounds overcomplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zipWithIndex` and convert into `Map[String, List[String]]`. Each `key` will be of form `group_0`, `group_1` etc

```
val map = x.zipWithIndex.map(x => s"group_${x._2}" -> x._1).toMap
```

Access each list using key

```
map("group_0")
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> x.zipWithIndex.map(x => s"group_${x._2}" -> x._1).toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(group_0 -> List(Nike, Apple), group_1 -> List(James, Mike))

scala> res4("group_0")
res6: List[String] = List(Nike, Apple)

scala> res4("group_1")
res7: List[String] = List(James, Mike)
```

@Manoj Kumar Dhakd idea to use `toMap` is better

Comment: @JoelBerkeley `groupBy` is overkill. edited the answer. 
Manoj Kumar Dhakd idea is better

Answer (score 0):

use function `zipWithIndex` and zip index with your lists then use `map` and create a `Map`

```
val listMap=x.zipWithIndex.map(grp=>"group_"+grp._2.toString->grp._1).toMap
```

Display your output like below

```
listMap.foreach(x=>println(x._1+"="+x._2))

//output:
group_0=List(Nike, Apple)
group_1=List(James, Mike)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.zipWithIndex.foreach{case (x,y)=>println("group_"+y+": List[String] = "+x)}
```

**Then, in Scala REPL:**

```
scala>  val x: List[ List[String]] = List(List("Nike","Apple"), List("James", "Mike"))
x: List[List[String]] = List(List(Nike, Apple), List(James, Mike))

scala> x.zipWithIndex.foreach{case (x,y)=>println("group_"+y+": List[String] = "+x)}
group_0: List[String] = List(Nike, Apple)
group_1: List[String] = List(James, Mike)
```